# How can I return multiple datasets from a Controller?

Tags: c#, view, datatable, controller, asp-net-mvc-1

Returning a single DataTable from a Controller works fine for me:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    dtable = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(SQL.SelectUnitsQuery, CommandType.Text, null);
    ViewBag.Units = dtable;
    return View(dtable);
}
```

I'm able to access it from the corresponding View like so:

```
@using System.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Platypus Report Scheduler";

    DataTable ds = ViewBag.Units as DataTable;
    var rows = from x in ds.AsEnumerable()
               select new
               {
                   unit = x.Field<string>("unit")
               };
}
```

But I need to reference multiple datasets; I tried this in the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    dtable = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(SQL.SelectUnitsQuery, CommandType.Text, null);
    ViewBag.Units = dtable;

    DataTable rpts = new DataTable();
    rpts = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable("select ReportName from ReportsLU", CommandType.Text, null);
    ViewBag.Reports = rpts;

    return View(dtable, rpts);
}
```

...but it won't compile; I get, "*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'string'" for "dtable*" and the same error for arg 2 ("rpts"). Also, "*The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(string, string)' has some invalid arguments*"

What is the way to work around this? Return a generic list of DataTable from the Controller? Populate the subsequent DataTables directly in the View? Or...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solution.

The first is to use `ViewBag` as you already do. The second solution (and in my personal opinion the best) is to create a new model that contains all data that you need to use in the view.

First implementation:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    dtable = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(SQL.SelectUnitsQuery, CommandType.Text, null);
    ViewBag.Units = dtable;

    DataTable rpts = new DataTable();
    rpts = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable("select ReportName from ReportsLU", CommandType.Text, null);
    ViewBag.Reports = rpts;

    return View();
}
```

You don't need to pass `dtable` and `rpts` to `View` method in this case because values are in `ViewBag`.

```
@using System.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Platypus Report Scheduler";

    DataTable ds = ViewBag.Units as DataTable;
    DataTable ds2 = ViewBag.Reports as DataTable;

    // Some other beautiful things
}
```

Second implementation:

```
public class YourModel {
    public DataTable dt1 { get; set; }
    public DataTable dt2 { get; set; }
    public DataTable dt3 { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    YourModel model = new YourModel();

    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    dtable = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(SQL.SelectUnitsQuery, CommandType.Text, null);
    model.dt1 = dtable;

    DataTable rpts = new DataTable();
    rpts = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable("select ReportName from ReportsLU", CommandType.Text, null);
    model.dt2 = rpts;

    return View(model);
}
```

Now in the view:

```
@model YourModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Platypus Report Scheduler";

    // Retrive data in this way:
    // Model.dt1
    // Model.dt2

    // Some other beautiful things
}
```

In the view `@model YourModel` is fundamental!

Comment: Thanks; I used your second/suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to provide to View method is a model which can be a class containing 2 data tables:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public DataTable DataTable1 { get; set; }
    public DataTable DataTable2 { get; set; }
}
```

The error you have explains that the overload you are using (`View(string viewName, object model)`) accepts the name of the view and model.

Comment: Thanks, this got me thinking in the right direction.